# How to save additional information in the metadata of a jpg file with the System.Drawing.Bitmap class

Tags: c#, .net, bitmap, metadata, jpeg

I would like to know how to add additional information in a jpg file, I want to do it in the following way, once the file sequence has been created to save it where I want to automatically add the properties that I need to the metadata, I have two methods, one to save the property and another to get the value of that property, at the moment I'm only interested in the one it saves, but I don't know how to implement it to save the information, can someone help me with this problem please, it's the first time I've had to do something like that

I am guided by the following example
[Adding extra info to an image file](https://dejanstojanovic.net/aspnet/2014/november/adding-extra-info-to-an-image-file/#code_start)

[Class ModifyMetadata](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJkO1.png)

```
protected void DownloadToFile(DownloadInfo Info, string filepath)
    {
        using (var stream = new SDKStream(filepath, FileCreateDisposition.CreateAlways, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
        {
            DownloadData(Info, stream.Reference);

            stream.Close();

            var bitmap = new Bitmap(filepath);

            var newMetadata = Extensions.SetMetaValue(bitmap, MetaProperty.Title, "Esto es un titulo para la imagen");

            bitmap.Save(newMetadata);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to do `bitmap.Save(filepath);` as the result of the extension function is just the same bitmap you give it (it's a "fluent" function).

Other notes:

- `bitmap` needs a `using`.
- The file remains open until the bitmap is disposed, so you need to copy it to a separate `MemoryStream` first. If you were saving to a different location then you don't need to do this.
- You don't need to read bitmaps from files, you can pass a `MemoryStream` directly to `new Bitmap()`. This also means you don't need to worry about the file already being open. I'm not sure whether `SDKStream` supports writing to a `MemoryStream` though, but if so then you can also remove the stream copying.
- That's not how extension functions should be used, you are supposed to do `bitmap.SetMetaValue(MetaProperty.Title, ...`

```cs
protected void DownloadToFile(DownloadInfo Info, string filepath)
{
    using (var stream = new SDKStream(filepath, FileCreateDisposition.CreateAlways, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
    {
        DownloadData(Info, stream.Reference);
    }

    using var bitmap = new Bitmap(new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(filepath)))
    {
        bitmap.SetMetaValue(MetaProperty.Title, "Esto es un titulo para la imagen");
        bitmap.Save(filepath);
    }
}
```

Comment: What does newMetadata refer to?

Comment: Sorry copy-paste typo

Comment: did you try this? @pipex98 did this work for you? it seems like (for me) it doesn't save the meta data into the file..

Comment: No, I didn't have the code for this extension method, but that wasn't the point of the post. The point was to explain why `bitmap.Save(newMetadata);` was wrong.

Comment: Okay.. yeah - either the extension method doesn't exactly do what it should or the Save method doesn't save metadata. I also tried with File.WriteAllBytes and other methods to save... :D